# Можно ли поместить кучу текста в переменную?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, aiogram, бот

я начинающий разраб в Python не очень опытный.
У меня вопрос можно ли всю эту гору текста с переменными поместить в какую-то переменную, к примеру crypoText? И чтобы из этого списка можно было удалять текст, к примеру чтобы в боте в Telegram  у меня было 1) Bitcoin - курс его 2) Ethereum — курс 3) Doge Coin — курс

Можно сделать так чтобы при помощи кнопки в Telegram можно было отключить ну например пункт 3) Doge Coin.

И чтобы вывелось:

Bitcoin — курс $
Ethereum — курс $
без Doge Coin
[image: code]

У меня есть рабочая кнопка "Настройки"[image: button]

Там я создам ещё одну менюшку которая будет, тоже открыватся при помощи кнопки, там будет несколько кнопок с названиями криптовалют на каждую нажму и там будет Удалить из Списка и Добавить в список, желательно чтобы от ситуации был текст в кнопке к примеру Удалить из списка если криптовалюта есть в списке, или же Добавить в список если она отсутствует.

Ссылка на весь код бота: https://pastebin.com/WQQ8HRWx
Markups.py: https://pastebin.com/McyzErVg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно можно! Код ниже:

```py
def text_gen(values: dict,
             off_list: list) -> str:
    """
    Args:
        values - json объект в {формате "валюта": значение}
        off_list - список отключённых валют, например ["Doggy"]
    """
    text = str()
    for value in values: # перебираем json рбъект values
        if value not in off_list: # проверяем, нет ли этой валюты
                                  # в списке отключенных валют off_list
            text += f"{value} — {values[value]} $\n" # если валюты нет в списке отключенных - добавляем
                                                     # текст с ней и её значением в переменную text
    return text # возвращаем переменную text


print(text_gen(values={
                  "Bitcoin": 1000000,
                  "Ethereum": 5000,
                  "Doggy": 10
                  },
               off_list=["Doggy"])) # вызываем функцию text_gen, передавая ей
                                    # необходимые значения, и выводим результат
```

На выходе мы получим:

```
>>> Bitcoin — 1000000 $
    Ethereum — 5000 $
```

Извиняюсь, если в ответе есть грамматические/синтаксические ошибки. Пишу ответ в полночь, хочу спать

Comment: А как-то тут каждый параметр можно присвоить к ID пользователя?

В Telegram мой бот будет не для личного пользования, а для публичного, ибо вроде-бы у бота просто поменяется параметр, и он пропадет вроде-бы у всех

Comment: можно хранить список отключенных валют в базе данных

Comment: Что-то слишком запутанный код, для меня как не очень опытного..